# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{x \to 1} (x^3 - 1) / (x - 1)$

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^3 - 1}{x - 1}$$

As $x$ approaches to $1$, if I use the substitution method, it will become undefined. Then, I tried to multiply it by its conjugate but I still get undefined answer. How can I solve it?

Comment: I've edited your question to include mathjax to say what I think you intended. Please verify that it's the correct expression.

Comment: Beside the remarkable identity given in answers, what about L'Hospital rule ?

Comment: Here is a generalization of this question: [Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}{\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}}=n$ for all integer n without L'Hôpital](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866327/prove-that-lim-x-rightarrow-1-fracxn-1x-1-n-for-all-integer-n-withou)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are cleaner and require no unnecessary machinery, but here's another method you can try if you can't spot the factorisation for messier expressions (but should be used with care). When evaluated at $x=1$, you get $\frac{0}{0}$, which is in an indeterminate form. This hints at L'Hospital Rule, which says that if

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \frac{0}{0}$$
then
$$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Note that we arrive at our answer if $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists, or else we try again.

In your case, $f(x)=x^3-1$, $\implies$ $f'(x)=3x^2$. Likewise, $g(x)=x-1$, $\implies$ $g'(x)=1$. Can you continue?

Comment: I found a question which match this condition and I apply it to the limit $\lim_{x \to 1) (2-(x+3)^1/2)/ (x - 1)$

Comment: finally I get answer of -1/4 instead of 1/4

Comment: ohh... I think that the answer in the book is not correct (1/4). After I use calculator to solve it, I get -1/4. Thank you for teaching me this new method

Comment: If you have doubts about your textbook's answer, you can always consult WolframAlpha. You're welcome.

Comment: This method also works if you your limit evaluates at $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

$$x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.

Comment: How to factorise it? I only know x-1 is one of the factors.

Comment: So, divide $x-1$ into $x^3-1$.  You can do this either by long division or synthetic division.

Comment: In general, $x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$, if $n>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You will have $$\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}{(x-1)}$$ and $x\ne 1$
since $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)$$